# I have been aware or I'm aware

Tags: perfect-constructions

I wrote this sentence "I have been aware, that my job is good" but my friend told me is not correct an answer. He said "I'm aware that my job is good"

Why I can't use present perfect?

Comment: *Am aware* is a stative predicate, in the simple present expressing the state that results from becoming aware.  Japanese predicates like 知る and 気づく are typically punctual, expressing the point of time when the state begins; they appear as 知っている and 気づいている when you want to express the resulting state.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that "I am aware" means that you are aware *right now*, with no indication of when you became aware. As a response in an argument ("I am aware of that, but"), it suggests that whatever you are aware of is so obvious or so unimportant that no more modification is necessary. "I have been aware" means that you have been aware for some unspecified duration. "I have been aware since..." or "I have been aware for..." specifies the duration.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to convey. "I have been aware for some time that my job is good" is gramatically correct. "I am aware that my job is good," is also grammatically correct. I have been aware of how hard it is to write short answers, but I never knew how hard until I wrote this.